# A more complicated Countif (Google docs)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple `countif:= Countif(A1:A5,"statement")`. And I want it to count the statement n times if it appears n times in my cell A1 (plus of course the number of times it appears on the other cells).

How do I that? And How should it be written in the cell? Is it possible to use vectors and matrices? So that a cell can be written in the following way :=[statement 1,statement 2... etc].

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `=countifs`, see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550.

> Returns the count of a range depending on multiple criteria.
>
> #### Sample Usage
>
> ```
> COUNTIFS(A1:A10, ">20", B1:B10, "<30")   
> COUNTIFS(A7:A24, ">6", B7:B24, "<"&DATE(1969,7,20))   
> COUNTIFS(B8:B27, ">" & B12, C8:C27, "<" & C13, D8:D27, “<>10”)
> ```
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])   
>
> criteria_range1 - The range to check against criterion1.   
> criterion1 - The pattern or test to apply to criteria_range1.  
> criteria_range2, criterion2... - [ OPTIONAL ] - Additional ranges and criteria to check; repeatable
> ```